# jq update json document to alter an array element

Tags: json, select, jq, edit

I know this has to be simple, but for some reason it's eluding me how to find an element given a condition and modify one of its fields.  The doc should be fully output (`sed` style) with the edit made.

```
{
  "state": "wait",
  "steps": { 
    "step1": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"wait" },
      { "name":"Bar",    "state":"wait" }
    ],
    "step2": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"wait" },
      { "name":"Zoinks", "state":"ready" }
    ],
    "step3": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"cancel" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm expecting something like this should be workable.

`jq '. | (select(.steps[][].name=="Foo" and .steps[][].state=="wait") |= . + {.state:"Ready"}'`

or

`jq '. | (select(.steps[][]) | if (.name=="Foo" and .state=="wait") then (.state="Ready") else . end)`

The desired output, of course, would be

```
{
  "state": "wait",
  "steps": { 
    "step1": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"ready" },
      { "name":"Bar",    "state":"wait" }
    ],
    "step2": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"ready" },
      { "name":"Zoinks", "state":"ready" }
    ],
    "step3": [
      { "name":"Foo",    "state":"cancel" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Instead, when I'm not getting cryptic errors, I'm either modifying a top-level field in the document or modifying the field for *all* the elements or repeated the entire doc multiple times.

Any insights greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

p.s. is there a better syntax than [] to wildcard the named-elements under steps?  Or after the pipe to identify the indices discovered by the select?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `.steps[][]` into a `select` call that chooses the objects with the desired `name` and `state` values, then set the `state` value on the result.

```
$ jq '(.steps[][] | select(.name == "Foo" and .state == "wait")).state = "ready"' tmp.json
{
  "state": "wait",
  "steps": {
    "step1": [
      {
        "name": "Foo",
        "state": "ready"
      },
      {
        "name": "Bar",
        "state": "wait"
      }
    ],
    "step2": [
      {
        "name": "Foo",
        "state": "ready"
      },
      {
        "name": "Zoinks",
        "state": "ready"
      }
    ],
    "step3": [
      {
        "name": "Foo",
        "state": "cancel"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can help confirm this using `diff` (the first `jq` just normalizes the formatting so that only the changes made by the second one show up in the diff):

```
$ diff <(jq . tmp.json) <(jq '...' tmp.json)
7c7
<         "state": "wait"
---
>         "state": "ready"
17c17
<         "state": "wait"
---
>         "state": "ready"
```

Comment: Hmmn, what version of jq are you using?  I've got jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe and for me the output is _only_ the flattened step objects, none of their enclosing structure, i.e. { "name": "Foo", "state":"ready" } {"name":"Bar", "state": wait" } ...  
The top level properties, the "steps" object, the "step1" array, all that context is gone.  Lacking commas, the output isn't even a legal JSON array.  

Any way to emit the full doc with just the surgical changes I need to make?  
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the way I did this for a complex document was following

```yaml
keya: AAA
keyb: BBB
keyc:
  arrayc:
  - name: item1
    someparam1: i1p1
    someparam2: i1p2
  - name: item2
    someparam1: i2p1
    someparam2: i2p2
```

```bash
yq '.keyc.arrayc = (.keyc.arrayc|map((select(.name == "item2")|.someparam2) |= "modified"))'
```

results in

```yaml
keya: AAA
keyb: BBB
keyc:
  arrayc:
    - name: item1
      someparam1: i1p1
      someparam2: i1p2
    - name: item2
      someparam1: i2p1
      someparam2: modified
```